# Parse HTML with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to parse a web page, so why when i use jsoup to connect, it auto change to the mobile site.

How can i get the page i want to get?
Thanks so much.

Comment: have you tried setting the userAgent to one of the desktop browser user agent strings?

Comment: I view with browser that's ok. But use jsoup to parse it, it auto to change to mobile site. I don't know why.

Comment: @user: do you *understand* the comment of Ben? If not, you should say that so instead of giving a completely unrelated answer. For example, "What is an userAgent?". Then we can help you better.

Comment: Yes, i understood. I have done. Thanks Ben, thanks BalusC

Comment: What is the url you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Which user agent have you used then?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a wiretrace? Or use your own http client and pass the String/Stream to Jsoup

Comment: Download WireShark at www.wireshark.org